# Custom option swatch stuck

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, cache, custom-options, swatches

I use custom option images to select a text font. Sometimes when I visite the productpage it is suddenly not possible to select another option. For some weird reason the custom option is stuck. Refreshing te page will fix it but it's very annoying. It seems to happen randomly.

**Check my screen video here (issue appears / is stuck on 0:24)**

https://share.vidyard.com/watch/HstNJVrKt3xWDi47FuePqQ?

**Or try it yourself**

https://naambordencentrale.nl/naamplaatje-kunststof-wit-8x2-cm.php

I've tried several changes in my htaccess file but without result. Also compare the html between working and not working page. Nothing to seer.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

[image: Custom image swatch stuck]